# Why does this if statement return `true`?

Tags: ruby

I had `customer.id` to equal `171`. Right after I perform the following `if`-statement, it returns `"customer.id = 0"`:

```
customer.id #=>    171
if customer.id = 0
  puts "customer.id = 0" # => customer.id = 0
end
```

Can anyone explain why this is the case?

Comment: You're using an assignment operator `=` instead of comparision operator `==`.

Comment: Your assumption in the question "the `if`-statement returns `true`" is wrong. It does not return `true`, but returns a truthy value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making assignment:

```
if customer.id = 0
```

It should be comparison:

```
if customer.id == 0
```

Comment: this is why I started to use yoda conditions ( `if 0 == customer.id` ), where you cannot be mistaken

Comment: @shivam Thanks. Realised that myself and then came back here to apologise for wasting people's time with silly questions. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @user3385136 No reason for apologies. Its a healthy human behavior to make silly mistakes every now and then. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ruby considers that `false` and `nil` are the only two "falsy" values, while everything else is "truthy". This is by definition and can not be modified (at least in MRI). This definition is used for all builtin operators like if, unless, while, until, cond ? if_truthy : if_falsey, ||, &&, ...

When write

```
if customer.id = 0  # customer.id = 0 will return 0
...
end
```

it is same as

```
if 0 # and 0 is truthy
...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Equality testing is performed with == in Ruby.